# Is it true that $n < p_n < n^2$ for $n > 2$ where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

First of all, I'm not a trained mathematician. I'm just a chemist with healthy interest in mathematics.

A few days ago I was wondering, is it true that $n < p_n < n^2$ for $n > 2$ where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number? 
And on the related question, lets say that is is true, 
Now let $1<a <b < 2$. 
What is the minimum value of $b - a$ such that 
$n^a < p_n < n^b$ for $n > 2$

Comment: Yes, this is true, and much stronger results are known. The prime number theorem is equivalent to the asymptotic $p_n \sim n \log n$, which also answers your second question.

Comment: So, what is $min(b-a)$ ?

Comment: There is no minimum. $n^a < p_n$ is not true for any $a > 1$ (it is only true for $a = 1$) and $p_n < n^b$ is true (eventually) for any $b > 1$.

Comment: So basically any non zero positive real number?

Comment: You mean $b - a$? Yes, $b - a$ can take any positive real value.